# What is the difference between insert and insertForce in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I found an insertForce method being called in Magento Core module. What is the difference of `insertForce` and `insert` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function lies here `vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php`

```
public function insertForce($table, array $bind)
{
    $this->rawQuery("SET @OLD_INSERT_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'");
    $result = $this->insert($table, $bind);
    $this->rawQuery("SET SQL_MODE=IFNULL(@OLD_INSERT_SQL_MODE,'')");

    return $result;
}
```

So obviously `insertForce` set a few MySQL parameters before calling the normal `insert` function. The most important thing we are looking at is `NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO`.

In short, if you relies on the auto increment column, inserting value `0` into that column with `insert` might not mean the inserted value will actually be `0` but rather the auto incremented value; while using `insertForce` will guarantee it to be `0`.

I found this explanation is best (from Drupal community but it has nothing to do with Drupal)

> NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO affects handling of AUTO_INCREMENT columns. Normally, you generate the next sequence number for the column by inserting either NULL or 0 into it. NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO suppresses this behavior for 0 so that only NULL generates the next sequence number.
>
> This mode can be useful if 0 has been stored in a table's AUTO_INCREMENT column. (Storing 0 is not a recommended practice, by the way.) For example, if you dump the table with mysqldump and then reload it, MySQL normally generates new sequence numbers when it encounters the 0 values, resulting in a table with contents different from the one that was dumped. Enabling NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO before reloading the dump file solves this problem. mysqldump now automatically includes in its output a statement that enables NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO, to avoid this problem.

From: https://www.drupal.org/forum/deprecated/deprecated-database-compatibility/2007-08-03/set-sql_mode-no_auto_value_on_zero